# Js / lodash group dates by rolling days (i.e. last 7 days)

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs, lodash

Hi I have an array of objects and I am able to group it and sum it by week or month by using lodash and moment.

```
      let arrayByWeek = _(someArray.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)))
      .groupBy( item => this.$moment.utc(item['date'], 'MM-DD-YY')
      .startOf( 'isoWeek') )
      .map((objs, key) => ({
        'date': this.$moment.utc(key).format('MM-DD-YY'),
          'addresses': objs.map ( obj => {
            return obj.someValue
          })
        }))
      .value()
```

Instead of having `startOf('week') I would like to group it by **7 rolling days**. So basically I would like to know that last 7 days and the previous 7 days, etc...

How can I do that? Is there any way I can do it by using lodash and moment?